# Can masturbation cure insomnia?

Tags: sleep, masturbation

I've come across the claim that masturbation can cure insomnia at several places on the internet, including:

- Episode 1 of [The Principles of Pleasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Principles_of_Pleasure), which focuses on female orgasm.

> "We think sexual stimulation could help a number of different
> disorders. A lot of people say they masturbate to help themselves
> sleep at night but we don't know why cause no one has ever looked."

- a Health Central article, [*Could Masturbation Cure Your Insomnia?*](https://www.healthcentral.com/article/could-masturbation-cure-your-insomnia), which says it *may* help:

> Although masturbation is unlikely to cure long-term, chronic insomnia, it may certainly be of help if you're struggling with the occasional sleepless night.

- An [online article](https://www.redbookmag.com/love-sex/sex/a46591/health-benefits-of-masturbation/) (Taken from the comments)

> "Orgasms release prolactin, which has a soporific effect," he explains, meaning that the hormone plays a role in inducing sleep.

I'm wary of these claims.

Can someone give some references that support or push back against this claim? Surely, there should/must have been some research into this.

Comment: I'm still unclear if this is question is asking if "masturbation can help you get to sleep" or "masturbation can cure insomnia, the sleep disorder".

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones "masturbation can cure insomnia, the sleep disorder" though the answer to either question should be correlated.

Comment: not really. just getting some sleep doesn't cure insomnia. At most it helps suppress some of its symptoms.

Comment: @jwenting source?

Comment: Rather you give should sources that it does :) But for example do remember that insomnia is not a single condition. It's in itself a symptom of one of quite a few diseases, which have quite disparate causes (and thus cures).